# Job execution in a jee environment

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, job-scheduling

I am working on an application that gives its users the ability to do financial transactions. I have some operations that need some days to be executed. 
So I want to know if there is a way to execute these operations in the expected day without my intervention, I mean it should be automatically done by the system.
I am actually working with spring framework and I have done some researches and find out the Task Execution and Scheduling supported by spring framework. but I don't know if this is a good choice for my case because I don't know if this job executer will work even if my application is not running and as you know the transactions execution should be done with or without running the application.
I am new to spring framework and especially to this job thing.
can anyone please explain to me this 'Job' concept and how to use it in my case.

Comment: Write cronjob shell script it'll be easier than scheduler in java

Comment: thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling Tasks with spring is very reliable, however your application must be running.
You can use cron expressions to set the trigger, in this example it will run every day from Monday to Friday at 2a.m.

```
@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ScheduledTasks.class);

    private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

    @Scheduled(cron="0 0 2 * * MON-FRI")
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    }
}
```

here how to build cron expressions spring like

Example patterns:

```
"0 0 * * * *" = the top of every hour of every day.
"*/10 * * * * *" = every ten seconds.
"0 0 8-10 * * *" = 8, 9 and 10 o'clock of every day.
"0 0 6,19 * * *" = 6:00 AM and 7:00 PM every day.
"0 0/30 8-10 * * *" = 8:00, 8:30, 9:00, 9:30, 10:00 and 10:30 every day.
"0 0 9-17 * * MON-FRI" = on the hour nine-to-five weekdays
"0 0 0 25 12 ?" = every Christmas Day at midnight
```